# Identify suitable point to become center of circles that are able cover all points in a region

Tags: geometry, coordinates, radius

I have a list of 10 thousand points (latitude,longitude). I want to identify suitable points to become the center point of circles with fixed radius that are able to cover all the points as shown in below.

Is there any available package to provide the below output? I am looking for the fastest way to do this.

[image]

Comment: Is it required that the number of circles is the smallest possible? If so this seems to be related to the notion of _r-covering number_ N(r) of a set, in case that keyword helps searching for an implementation of an algorithm